# List to matrix using Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a list which I want to convert into matrix. But when using numpy I am not able to remove inverted commas.

List -

```
[['b', 'd', 'a', 'c'], ['b1', 'd1', 'a1', 'c1'], ['b2', 'd2', 'a2', 'c2']]
```

Using Numpy -

```
[['b' 'd' 'a' 'c']
 ['b1' 'd1' 'a1' 'c1']
 ['b2' 'd2' 'a2' 'c2']]
```

What I need -

```
b  d  a  c
b1 d1 a1 c1
b2 d2 a2 c2
```

Thanks

Comment: The "Inverted commas" you say are the single quotes - " ' " ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'I need:'? Do you need to print?

Comment: Is this just a print display issue, or do you need to do something in `numpy` with the matrix of strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to numpy you can make it pure python.

```
a = [['b', 'd', 'a', 'c'], ['b1', 'd1', 'a1', 'c1'], ['b2', 'd2', 'a2', 'c2']]
for b in a:
    print ' '.join(b)
```

Answer (score 2):

*Quotes* with the text means that you have the object of `str` type. You need not worry about them because when you do `print`, these will be removed. For example:

```
>>> my_list = [['b', 'd', 'a', 'c'], ['b1', 'd1', 'a1', 'c1'], ['b2', 'd2', 'a2', 'c2']]
>>> my_list[0][0]  # without print, shows content with quotes
'b'
>>> print my_list[0][0]  # with print, content without quotes
b
>>>
```

In order to print the content in the format you mentioned, you may do:

```
>>> for sub_list in my_list:
...     print ' '.join(sub_list)  # join to make single of object in sub_list
...
b d a c
b1 d1 a1 c1
b2 d2 a2 c2
```

where `my_list` is the list mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is to print it such that cells are space separated and rows are line-break separated :

```
print ('\n'.join([' '.join(i) for i in lst]))
```